# Powermockito mock static method matcher not working

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

When I'm trying to mock a static method with a String input, mocked stub is getting executed when I give a specific String, but when I use anyString(), it does not work as expected.

```java
public class Foo {
    public static String staticInput(String s) {
        System.out.println("staticInput called");
        return "static " + s;
    }
}
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Foo.class})
public class TestMockito {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Foo.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn("dummyStaticStub").when(Foo.class, "staticInput", "1");
        System.out.println(Foo.staticInput("1"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Foo.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn("dummyStaticIn").when(Foo.class, "staticInput", anyString());
        System.out.println(Foo.staticInput("1"));
    }
}
```

test1 prints:

> dummyStaticStub

test2 prints:

> staticInput called
>   static 1

Answer (score 0):

You can change the approach a little and use `PowerMockito.mockStatic` instead

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Foo.class})
public class TestMockito {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Foo.class);
        Mockito.when(Foo.staticInput("1")).thenReturn("dummyStaticStub");
        System.out.println(Foo.staticInput("1"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Foo.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Foo.staticInput(anyString())).thenReturn("dummyStaticIn");
        System.out.println(Foo.staticInput("1"));
    }
}
```

Reference [Using PowerMock with Mockito: Mocking Static Method](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method)